# How to download a image in flickr by Python urllib.urlretrieve()?

Tags: python, urllib, flickr

I have a problem that when dowloading a image from flickr.com,the python function `urllib.urlretrieve()` always return  an error

```
[Errno socket error] (10060, 'Operation timed out')
```

for example:

```
import urllib

url = "http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2659/4207030547_23e6000d29_o.gif"
urllib.urlretrieve(url,"C://tmp.gif")
```

I am Chinese,and I dont know if the "time out" has anything to do with the speed of the the internet in China.

Now it falied in downing the .gif! what should i do about this? THX~~~

Any suggestion is appreciated~~~

Comment: What Python version are you using?

Comment: Shouldn't you use `C:\\` instead of the forward slashes? I don't think it has anything to do with the error though.

Comment: I use python2.5 +Blender,it does not matther,+Trufa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce.

The exact same code downloaded the picture.

I'm using python 2.7

It has to do either with the server (at that time) or with your internet connection.

[image]

Comment: @kaitian I'm from Uruguay, if I was you, just in case, try it from other host other that flickr to be absolutely sure.

Comment: +Trufa  Uruguay, football is a popular in your contry? I tyied a China website ,it works...  I just prepare for the GRE exam,I want to go America. thank you very much

Comment: @kaitian ideed,latest champion of america, fourth in las world championship :)

Comment: +Trufa Luis Alberto Suárez Díaz （路易斯·阿尔贝托·苏亚雷斯 ,this is his  chnnese name） is very lucky.haha

Comment: @kaitian hehe nice to know, what would be the "luis suarez" part? That is how he is known. BTW, have you tried downloading from another URL?

Comment: +Trafa I have tries many urls of china website ,they all works.the image from flickr.com can be downloaded by chrome,firefox .Unfortunately,It can not be downloaded by my application.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [`urllib2`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) library instead, which allows you to specify the timeout (in Python 2.6+).

Comment: urllib2 does not have the function urlretrieve~~~

Comment: @kaitian - this is true, but `urllib2.urlopen()` returns a file-like object that can be streamed to disk if desired. It requires a little more boilerplate (you have to `.read()` from the object, and then `.write()` to your on-disk file), but it gives you more flexibility.

Comment: But urlopen can not download the picture,yes? I do nor know what to do whit your idea... sorry for that

Comment: `f = urllib2.urlopen(...); o = open('output.file', 'w'); while True: [ buffer = f.read(1024); o.write(buffer); if not buffer: [ break; ] ]` (Hard to write python in comments, but maybe this'll help you get the idea.)

Comment: thanks very much... I tried it in using a function from VC,called URLDownloadToFile() ,and it works.thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The reason you cannot download the image from flickr is that, China has a freaking WALL that's blocking you! You can try to use a VPN that works globally on your computer (so that your python program also runs under this VPN environment),
or,

you set up the proxies in, let's say `requests`, then you can download images from those websites that are blocked from China.

```
import requests

proxies = {
 “http”: “http://10.10.10.10:8000”,   # just an example
 “https”: “http://10.10.10.10:8000”,  # just an example
}
r = requests.get(“http://example_url.com”, proxies=proxies)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the "get" method. I have recently had to do the same thing and I solved the problem with the following:

```
import requests
url = "https://www.python.org/static/community_logos/python-logo-master-v3-TM.png"
try:
    r = requests.get(url,allow_redirects = True)
    if(r.status_code == 200):
        open("Image.jpg","wb").write(r.content)
    elif(r.status_code == 404):
        print("Image not found at the URL")
    else:
        print("Unknown error occurred.")
except:
    print("Could not establish connection with the site URL.")
```