# 'list' object has no attribute 'strip' error when using urllib.urlretrieve

Tags: python, regex, image

Hello I'm trying to download images from Flickr.com using python 2.7 and this is my code

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from urllib import urlopen
from re import findall
from Tkinter import *
import urllib, cStringIO
import random
photo_window=Tk()
photo_window.title('Photo Browser')
import base64
url = '"https://www.flickr.com/photos/flickr/galleries/72157644537473411/"'
regex = '<img src="([^"]+)".*>'
photofile=urllib.urlopen(url)
raw_data=photofile.read()
pattern = re.compile(regex)
download=re.findall(pattern,raw_data)
urllib.urlretrieve(download, "local-filename.gif")
```

i'm trying to download images as many as i can by using `findall`
but it always comes up with an error:

```
'list' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

can i get any helps with this problem?

Comment: `urllib.urlretrieve` expects a string, not a list.

Comment: Possible dup : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749649/how-to-download-a-image-in-flickr-by-python-urllib-urlretrieve

Comment: This is in no way a duplicate of the cited question, above.   Same function is being asked about, completely different problem.

Comment: I don't see how this code can produce that error message.   The variable `url` is not being assigned  a valid URL (because the string contains double quotes) and `urlopen` barfs on this.  At least on my system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the working code

```
# imports
import re # mind this! It won't work with from re import findall 
photo_window=Tk()
photo_window.title('Photo Browser')
import base64
url = "https://www.flickr.com/photos/flickr/galleries/72157644537473411/"
regex = '<img src="([^"]+)".*>'
photofile=urllib.urlopen(url)
raw_data=photofile.read()
pattern = re.compile(regex)
 download=re.findall(pattern,raw_data)
t=0
for x in download:
    urllib.urlretrieve(x, "local-filename-%d.gif" %t )
    t+=1
```

You need to make a string out of a list with `''.join(download)` as `urlretrieve`'s first argument must be a string. `url='"smth"'` is also incorrect, you'd better do `url="smth"`. Moreover, `from re import findall` won't work as you're using `re.findall(smh)` in your code, so you need `import re`.

The images will be saved to files called *local-filename-0.gif*, *local-filename-1.gif*, *local-filename-2.gif*, etc.

Comment: FWIW, it _did_ work with the imports he's using, for me ;)  Or at least, it appeared to...

Comment: I don't understand how this works.  Each item returned by `findall()` is itself a full URL.   I'm not aware that you can pass multiple URLs catenated together in a string to urlretrieve.  Can you?

Comment: @GreenAsJade, it turned out that we can't do it. How stupid of me.  I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 2):

As @nhahtdh mentioned in comments, the error message you reported is because your variable "download" is a list (the result of `findall()`) not a string.

`urlretrieve` expects a string.

Comment: I had to edit the code to fix the `url=` line before I could reproduce this error, BTW.